# Modeling hardware registers using C struct and union

Tags: c, struct, unions, cpu-registers

I'm working on an embedded CPU, and need to write C tests that verify the entire system. One of the things to check is access to all registers in the system.

I already have the register modeled using a combination of struct (to differentiate the register fields) and union (to be able to access the register as a whole).
For example:

```
typedef unsigned long Uint32;

typedef volatile struct
{
    volatile Uint32 Divider:    4;      //3:0
    volatile Uint32 Unused:     28;     //31:4
}XClkRstDivBits; 

typedef union
{
    Uint32 all;
    XClkRstDivBits bit;
}XClkRstDivRegs;
```

In this way, I can access only the register field, or access the entire register:

```
#define REG_ADDRESS 0x000A
volatile XClkRstDivRegs *ClkRstDivReg = (XClkRstDivRegs *) REG_ADDRESS;

ClkRstDivReg->all = 0xA5A5A5A5; //Access entire register
ClkRstDivReg->bit.Divider = 0x5;
```

I have a few registers defined in this way, some have a few fields, all allocated differently.
Note the 'Unused' part, most registers have a few unused or reserved bits, which are not written to and are read as zero.

I want to write a a macro that can read from a register and check if the data on the register equals to the one I expect. But, I want this function to be able to:

1. Work on all registers
2. Automatically zero or disregard the Unused bits when comparing the result to the expected result.

The macro should look like this:

```
#define READ_AND_COMPARE_REG(Reg, ExData, Rdata) ...
```

Where Reg is the pointer to the register ; ExData is an unsigned 32 bit data that contains the expected data, but without a mask on the unused bits, Rdata is an unsigned 32 bit variable to store the read from the register.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: you could take a new instance of your register struct, set all bits to 1, then set `Unused` to zero, then `bit` becomes your mask

Comment: Yes, but then it would only work on that specific struct. I would like a general macro to work on all registers.

Comment: I'd assume all your union/structs have a field `all` and a field `unused`. If you pass the struct type to your macro, this macro could declare two variables of the struct type, assign both the expected and read value to `all`, set both `unused` fields to zero and then compare the contents of both `all`.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right and it seems that there's no workaround to passing the type as an argument to macro. I think you can post this as an answer.